# Is there an efficient way to solve a system of linear equations with an almost tridiagonal sparse matrix?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have a problem where I need to solve a linear system of equation $Ax = b$ where the matrix A is almost tridiagonal, except for elements on the last two columns (see below).

I need to solve such a system at each time step and the matrix changes every time but keeps the same form. For the moment, I am using a LU decomposition to solve this system ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#MATLAB_code_example)), but I thought since the matrix is very sparse and almost tridiagonal, there would be a faster way. Could there be a slightly modified version of the Thomas algorithm for example?

I have tried to use Matlab's gmres function but it is not faster. Please note that my matrix is neither symmetric nor positive definite, so it limits the options that I have.

Here's the shape of the matrix in question:

[image]

Comment: Such an arrow shape is the aim of sparse reordering methods, usually with wider bandwidth around diagonal and right side (and usually also the bottom). So any source on sparse methods should also contain ideas on efficient solution methods for this structure.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom you have two equations for the last two variables. Solve that system and substitute the result to eliminate the last two columns; then you have a tridiagonal system.